# Java EE WFLYCTL0412 Required services that are not installed

Tags: jpa, server, wildfly, javabeans, java-ee-6

Hi im trying to deploy a javaEE application in my wildfly server and when i try to run my server it throws me an exception about services that are not installed this happened any ideas what can be in conflict? Here is the output:

```
Deploying C:\wildfly-26.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments\ProyectoServidor.ear
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ProyectoServidor.ear\".\"ProyectoEJB-ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"ProyectoEJB-ejb.jar\" of deployment \"ProyectoServidor.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.fannog.proyectoservidor.utils.Encryptor with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.ProyectoServidor.ear.ProyectoEJB-ejb.jar\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jasypt/util/password/StrongPasswordEncryptor
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor from [Module \"deployment.ProyectoServidor.ear.ProyectoEJB-ejb.jar\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"ProyectoServidor.ear\".WeldStartService",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"ProyectoServidor.ear\".beanmanager"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"ProyectoServidor.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"ProyectoServidor.ear\".beanmanager, jboss.deployment.unit.\"ProyectoServidor.ear\".WeldStartService]"]
}
C:\Users\facun\git\servidor\nbproject\build-impl.xml:330: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ejb is using org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor which is not provided in your application thus you  are getting a ClassNotFoundException:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor from [Module "deployment.ProyectoServidor.ear.ProyectoEJB-ejb.jar" from Service Module Loader]"},

Comment: hi! @ehsavoie thanks for your reply, i have the jasypt.jar into my libraries folder also i have it into my  compile-time libraries, it supossed to provide to my ejb the org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor Class, but when i run my server is throws me this exception, if i go into the .jar details here is it the StrongPasswordEncryptor Class, the strange thing is that the password is encrypted correctly in de database, i just want to clear this error in the server deploy log

Comment: You should take a look at https://docs.wildfly.org/26/Developer_Guide.html#Class_Loading_in_WildFly

Comment: Thanks @ehsavoie im going to check it out